# i18next appends the default translation namespace to my namespaces

Tags: namespaces, internationalization, aurelia, i18next

I am using i18n - aurelia's wrapper of i18next with the following configuration:

```
  instance.i18next.use(Backend);

  return instance.setup({
    backend: {
      loadPath: 'assets/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },
    detectFromHeaders: false,
    lng: 'bg',
    fallbackLng: 'bg',
    ns: ['app', 'dp', 'management'],
    defaultNS: 'app',
    fallbackNS:'app',
    attributes: ['t', 'i18n'],
    useCookie: false,
    getAsync: false,
    debug: false
  });
```

I have a component that switches to a different language via the setLocale(language) function. It works fine for the translations, however, when I switch between the languages for some reason i18next adds the translation.json to my namespaces although I don't use it and it makes an xhr call to get it and I get a 404 error for translation.json - a namespace I don't even want in the first place. Is there an option to remove it altogether from the namespaces?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not part of Aurelia-I18N but one of i18next itself. The only workaround I found so far is to set the fallbackLng to false.

```
{
  backend: {                        
    loadPath: './locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json', 
  },
  lng : 'de',
  ns: ['foo'],
  defaultNS: "foo",
  attributes : ['t','i18n'],
  fallbackLng : false,  <----- SET THIS TO FALSE TO AVOID A SEARCH FOR translation NS
  debug : false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that can be tracked here: https://github.com/aurelia/i18n/issues/47

Comment: Thanks, I will be tracking the bug, hope it'll be resolved soon. I'm not sure if it's an i18n issue though. I think the error is in i18next because when I checked it was appending the translation.json to the namespaces array it has.

Comment: please upvote if this helped you, and accept if this answered your question